# Insert or get in Slick 3

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

I was trying to insert if not exists, and get the row if it does.
I come up with this:

```
def saveOrGet(u: User) = (for {
  userGet <- get(u.name).map(r => (r.id, r.active)).result.headOption
  id <- save(u) if userGet.isEmpty
} yield {
  userGet match {
    case Some((id, active)) => (User(Some(id), u.name, active), false)
    case None               => (User(Some(id), u.name, u.active), true)
  }
}).transactionally

private def get(name: String) = users.filter(_.name === name).take(1)

private def save(u: User) = users returning users.map(_.id) += u
```

**EDIT**

After making some modifications, now I get:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Action.withFilter failed
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try using `case _`, because it seems that it's possible to have something empty rather than `None`

```
userGet match {
    case Some((id, active)) => (User(Some(id), u.name, active), false)
    case _                  => (User(Some(id), u.name, u.active), true)
}
```

Comment: I edited the question. Anyway, that would be a problem that the compiler takes care of.